Does dried seaweed expire?
I just bought some dried nori from a pet store. However, the package they sold me expired a couple months ago.
Can I still safely utilize it?

if you google nori seaweed you will find a lot of information including how to store it.

Is that a use-by date, a sell-by date, or a best-before date? The latter is most common on foodstuffs.

Expiration dates are presented on products for a good reason. Of course, that reason is quite not applicable in the case of cooking salt (and other substances), but the rule is a rule.
Now, anyone telling you to ignore that information (the expiration date) takes a great risk - if something goes wrong, they can be blamed, of even criminally charged.
And even if they take the risk and tell you that, will you really totally trust them? Especially no-names from the internet? That would be dangerous business.
That is why in these cases, you need to make your own evaluation. Usually you try one a small quantity, wait, see if there are bad effects. After some more waiting, try again, maybe with greater quantity. And so on. I do that with some products, but I did it on my own responsibility. BUT I strongly advise AGAINST using expired products.
Now you have to understand what risks you are willing to take, for you and for your pet(s), and act accordingly.


the package they sold me expired a couple months ago

If they delivered an expired product, just return it, and demand to receive a replacement which is not expired. If it expired while you kept it, you need to make your own decision about how to proceed.
